# nodejs formidable detect empty file upload

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs i am learning how to upload files. I am using a middleware called formidable, its awsome, but i would like to find out how to skip empty attachment upload. The script below is ok, but it keep creating empty file which shouldn't happen. Thanks advance for any helps or suggestion.

```
var http = require('http');
var user = require('./user');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var util = require('util');
var filePath = path.join(__dirname + '/test.html');
var file = fs.readFileSync(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'})
var maxData = 2 * 1024 * 1024; //2mb
var connect = require('connect');
var formidable = require('formidable');


http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    if(request.method == 'POST')
    {
        response.writeHead('Content : text/html');
        var incoming = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        incoming.uploadDir = 'upload';
        incoming.on('fileBegin', function(field, file){
            console.log(file.name);
            if (file.name && file.name != ''){
                file.path += "-" + file.name;
                file.name = '';
                console.log(file.name);
            }
        }).on('file', function(filed, file){
            console.log('uploading...');
            response.write(file.name + ' gotted');
        }).on('end', function(){            
            response.end('Eveyrhitng in folder');
        })
        incoming.parse(request);
    }
    if(request.method == 'GET')
    {
        response.writeHead('Content : text/html');
        response.write(file);
        response.end('This is the end of it');
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

and here is my form

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- <input type="text" name="test">
            <input type="text" name="test2"> -->
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="file" name="file2">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is empty to you? A file with 0 byte?

Comment: 0 byte, so if i select name="file" with a file and leave the other one none selected and submit the form.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the `file.size` property, and if it is `0`, then the file field is empty.

Comment: that's OK but why does it create an empty file when no file has been selected at the client-end, is there a way to stop that?

Comment: I am also facing this issue and looking for solution to it. If there are 3 input files and you select only one then there are 3 files in the /tmp dir created